# Spring MVC ModelAndView attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, twitter-bootstrap

Hi.

I`m trying to integrate Spring MVC with bootstrap modal - having filter region I want to select item from modal form and set it to the filter via jQuery ajax.
Main idea: show modal popup when user clicks on button to select item, this popup must allow user to search in the list (ajax) and click submit button to select item.
To refresh popup data I return ModelAndView with filtered list of items, and then, if user click 'submit', I send selected index to server where I can get id by index in the list, but ModelMap (and Model too) does not contain this list. 
What am I doing wrong?

I have following structure:

Main JSP's:

#### main.jsp

```
 ....
 <div class="override side-nav raised" id="filter">
     <jsp:include page="filter.jsp"/>
 </div>
 ....
```

#### filter.jsp

```
<f:form method="get" cssClass="search" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/search"
    commandName="searchModel">
    ....
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="searchDpt"><s:message code="label.department"/></label>

        <div class="controls">
            <f:input id="searchDpt" cssClass="form-control col-sm-8" cssStyle="width: 75%;" path="dept"/>
            <button type="button" id="dsb_filter" class="btn btn-default col-sm-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectDeptModal"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    ....
</f:form>
```

Modal window for item selection:

#### modal.jsp

```
<div id="selectDeptModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
    style="display: none;">
    ....
    <div class="table-responsive" id="dept_table">
        <jsp:include page="deptTable.jsp"/>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="selectDept();"><s:message code="label.select"/></button>
</div>
```

And jQuery code for ajax search and POSTing data:

```
function search() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "departments",
        data: "name=" + $("#dpt_filter").val(),
        success: function (response) {
            $("#dept_table").html(response);
        }
    });
}

function getSelectedIndex() {
    var table = $("#dept_table").find("table")
    var selectedRows = table.find("tr.selected-row");
    var elements = [];
    if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
        table.find("tr.selected-row td.index-col").each(function (i, el) {
            elements.push(parseInt($(el).text()));
        });
    }
    return elements;
}

function selectDept() {
    var selected = getSelectedIndex()[0];

    if (selected == undefined || selected.length == 0) {
        $("#no_selection").removeClass("hidden");
        return;
    }

    $('#selectDeptModal').modal('hide');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deptSelected",
        data: { index: selected},
        success: function (response) {
            $("#filter").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller methods for handling JavaScript:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "departments")
public ModelAndView getDepartments(@RequestParam(required = false) String name, Model model) {
    LOG.debug(name);
    model.addAttribute("dpts", departmentService.filterByName(name));
    return new ModelAndView("selectDeptDialog/deptTable");
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "deptSelected")
public ModelAndView deptSelected(@RequestParam Long index, ModelMap model) {
    SearchModel sModel = (SearchModel) model.get("searchModel");
    sModel.setDept(index);
    Object depts = model.get("dpts");// = null

    return new ModelAndView("filter", model);
}
```

But when getting list of departments in deptSelected it is null.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "not working", specifically?

Comment: Sorry for not clear problem explanation. Editted question - when getting list of departments in deptSelected it is null

Comment: Is "index" null in your java method? What does your ModelMap look like when you debug?

Comment: @ElGuapo No, index is expected positive number. ModelMap contains values from controller methods annotated with ModelAttribute.
When I send request from View with key-value pair in Model i expect that this key-value pair will be available in controller method, handling this request. But after filling "dpts" attribute ( model.addAttribute("dpts", departmentService.filterByName(name));) i cant get it in the deptSelected method since ModelMap does not contain such key.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong you're expecting the model in both methods to be maintained between service calls? Model will be rewritten every time a call is made to your methods (I'm fairly sure).

Comment: @ElGuapo ouch... it seems, I misunderstanding some concepts. Thanks a lot! You can add it as answer so i`ll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelMaps don't keep their state between requests. You may, however, be able to get some of the same result using a @SessionAttribute, however, I don't think that will get your desired result, either.